# Deriving the wave equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, physics, wave-equation, electromagnetism

> Given:
>
> $$\nabla \times \mathbf  H = \frac{4\pi}{c} \mathbf  j \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1)$$
>
> $$\nabla \times \mathbf E = -\frac{1}{c} \frac{\partial \mathbf H}{\partial t} \ \ \ (2)$$
>
> $$\mathbf E = -\frac{\mathbf v}{c} \times \mathbf H \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (3)$$
>
> $$\rho \frac{\partial  \mathbf v}{\partial t} = \frac{1}{c}(\mathbf j \times \mathbf H) \ \ (4)$$
>
> **Derive the following PDE** (1D Wave Equation):
>
> $$\frac{\partial ^2 \mathbf H'}{\partial z^2} = \frac{4\pi\rho}{H_0^2}\frac{\partial ^2 \mathbf H'}{\partial t^2}$$
>
> Where $H'$ means a small perturbation of $H$.

We assume that the magnetic field is uniform and equal to:

$$\mathbf B = H_0 \hat z$$

Alright, so let's introduce the following perturbations:

$$\mathbf H = H_0 \hat z + H' \hat x$$

$$\mathbf E = + E' \hat y$$

$$\mathbf j = + j' \hat y$$

$$\mathbf v = + v' \hat x$$

While the density is assumed to remain constant.

All the perturbed quantities are assumed to be very small. Thus, the product of each other is negligible.

But how can we derive the stated wave equation out of the above equations?

**EDIT:**

Alright, so let's write down all equations.

- Combining $(1)$ and $(4)$ we get:

$$4\pi \rho \frac{\partial {\mathbf v}}{\partial t} = (\nabla\times \mathbf H)\times \mathbf H$$

Inserting perturbation equations into it and working out the RHS we get (let me know if you want me to include the steps):

$$4 \pi \rho \frac{\partial}{\partial t} v' \hat x = H_0 \Big(\frac{\partial H'}{\partial z} - \frac{\partial H_0}{\partial x}\Big) \hat x -\Big(H' \frac{\partial H'}{\partial y} + H_0\frac{\partial H_0}{\partial y}\Big) \hat y -H' \Big(\frac{\partial H'}{\partial z} - \frac{\partial H_0}{\partial x}\Big) \hat z$$

By equating components we get:

$$4 \pi \rho \frac{\partial}{\partial t} v' = H_0 \Big(\frac{\partial H'}{\partial z} - \frac{\partial H_0}{\partial x}\Big) \ \ \ (I)$$

$$H' \frac{\partial H'}{\partial y} = -H_0\frac{\partial H_0}{\partial y} \ \ \ (II)$$

$$\frac{\partial H'}{\partial z} = \frac{\partial H_0}{\partial x} \ \ \ (III)$$

- Inserting perturbation equations into equation $(2)$ and working out the LHS we get:

$$\frac{\partial E'}{\partial x} \hat z - \frac{\partial E'}{\partial z} \hat x = -\frac{\partial}{c\partial t} \Big(H_0 \hat z  + H' \hat x \Big) = -\frac{\partial}{c\partial t} H' \hat x$$

By equating components we get:

$$\frac{\partial E'}{\partial x} = -\frac{\partial}{c\partial t} H_0 = 0 \ \ \ (IV)$$

$$\frac{\partial E'}{\partial z} = \frac{\partial}{c\partial t} H' \ \ \ (V)$$

- Inserting perturbation equations into equation $(3)$ and working out the RHS we get:

$$E' \hat y = \frac{1}{c} v' H_0 \hat y$$

By equating components we (of course) get:

$$E' = \frac{1}{c} v' H_0 \ \ \ (VI)$$

OK! So I just have to work out the above six equations to get the desired wave equation...

Comment: You insert the expression for $H,E,j,v$ into the equations you got, combine them and try to extract the given combination. For example inserting the first equation into the fourth gives you $4\pi \rho \frac{d{\bf v}}{dt} = (\nabla\times H)\times H$. Insert and simplify. The third equation leads to $E' = v' H_0$. Use the second equation to relate $E'$ and $H'$. Combine these things and you will eventually get there.

Comment: @Winther thanks for your comment. I indeed get the equations you stated. I am using the second equation to relate $E'$ and $H$ and I've got $\nabla \times (E' \hat y) = -\frac{1}{c} \frac{\partial}{\partial t} (H_o \hat z + H' \hat x)$. When we apply the curl in the left hand side we get $-\frac{\partial E'}{\partial z} \hat x + \frac{\partial E'}{\partial x} \hat z = -\frac{1}{c} \frac{\partial}{\partial t} (H_o \hat z + H' \hat x)$   but does this lead to get the wave equation?

Comment: First write down what you get from **all** equations (and extract the components - the equation you have above gives you two equations). Then you can start to work on trying to get a wave equation out of it.

Comment: @Winther Thank you for your comments! I now get 6 equations, but how can I get the wave equations out of them? (please see above edit). I've been trying to build it up on equation V by deriving wrt to time both sides and wrt to z both sides as well but got messy...

Comment: Good. You can simplify the equations since $H_0$ is a constant so any derivative of it will vanish. Try to compute $\frac{d^2E'}{dtdz}$ from (V) and substitute (VI) - this gives you $H'_{tt}$ in terms of $v'_{tz}$. You can then combine this with taking the $z$-derivative of (I) (which also gives you $v'_{tz}$) and you are there. Also note that (II) and (III) comes from second order terms ($H'H'$) so these equations should not be included in the system.

Comment: $H_0$ is a constant and its derivatives will vanish, Indeed! I'll modify my equations above. I get $\frac{\partial ^2 \mathbf H'}{\partial z^2} = \frac{4\pi\rho}{c H_0^2}\frac{\partial ^2 \mathbf H'}{\partial t^2}$. The speed of light shows up when it shouldn't...

Comment: @Winther Well now I am thinking that the author may have taken $c=1$ for convenience. Could that be the case?

Comment: Check (VI). There is something missing here.

Comment: @Winther Absolutely! I missed the $1/c$ factor in equation (VI)! I will modify it. Thanks for your help. Please feel free to convert your comments into a response if you wish. I think you deserve credit for this.