# Find the general solution for the wave equation for waves in a closed loop.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant, wave-equation

A closed magnetic loop (see picture below) is partially submerged in the solar interior and partly in the [corona](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corona). When observed over time, it is clear that it behaves like an elastic band that can carry waves.

[image]

> **Find the general solution for the wave equation for the waves in the closed loop.** Assume periodicity and apply interface conditions at the photosphere.
>   For this case you need not worry about the curvature of the loop and you can stretch it as a straight line, but you need to apply periodicity at the ends. Solve means finding the eigenfrequencies and also the eigenfunctions.
>
> HINTS:
>
> 1) **You have to deal with 2 wave equations.** Note that the wave travels through different mediums; in the upper half through the corona and in the lower half through the solar interior.
>
> 2) **You have to end up with a** $[4 \times 4]$ **determinant.** You do not have to work out the determinant; you only have to show it. The eigenfrequencies (eigenvalues) can easily be done by a computer by equating the solution of the determinant to zero and solving that equation.

I could set up the problem correctly:

**We have two different Wave Equations:**

$$f_{tt} = v_1^2 f_{\theta \theta} \ \ \ for \ \ \ 0 < \theta < \pi \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1)$$

$$f_{tt} = v_2^2 f_{\theta \theta} \ \ \ for \ \ \ \pi < \theta < 2\pi \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (2)$$

**The periodic boundary conditions are as follows** (periodicity applies between $0$ and $2\pi$ only):

$$f(0, t) = f(2\pi, t) \ \ \ ; \ \ \ f_{\theta}(0, t) = f_{\theta}(2\pi, t) \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $$

**The interface conditions at the photosphere are:**

$$\lim\limits_{\theta \to \uparrow \pi} f(\theta, t) = \lim\limits_{\theta \to \downarrow \pi} f(\theta, t) \ \ \ \ \ ; \ \ \ \ \lim\limits_{\theta \to \uparrow \pi} f_{\theta}(\theta, t) = \lim\limits_{\theta \to \downarrow \pi} f_{\theta}(\theta, t)$$

**But I am stuck in how to solve it.** The method I normally apply is as follows:

$1)$ Assume separation of variables AKA $u(\theta, t) = \Theta(\theta)T(t)$.

$2)$ Study what are the solutions you get for the spatial part when the constant is: positive, zero and negative.

But I am not getting the eigenfunctions.

**We expect solutions of the form:**

$$(\theta, t) \rightarrow \Theta (\theta) e^{\pm i \omega t}$$

My in-detail work is here: [Constructing a determinant to get the eigenvalues associated to a pair of wave equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3482169/constructing-a-determinant-to-get-the-eigenvalues-associated-to-a-pair-of-wave-e)

Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT $0$**:

**These are my solutions:**

- After applying the periodic boundary conditions one gets:

$$\Theta (\theta) = A_1 \sin \Big( n \frac{\omega}{v_1} \theta \Big) \ \ \ \ \ (SOL.1)$$

$$\Theta (\theta) = A_2 \sin \Big( n \frac{\omega}{v_2} (2\pi - \theta) \Big) \ \ \ \ \ (SOL.2)$$

- After applying interface conditions one gets:

$$A_1 \sin \Big( n \frac{\omega}{v_1} \pi \Big) = A_2 \sin \Big( n \frac{\omega}{v_2} \pi \Big) \ \  \ \  \ \ \ \ \ (5)$$

$$n\frac{A_1}{v_1} \cos \Big( n \frac{\omega}{v_1} \pi \Big) = -n\frac{A_2}{v_2} \cos \Big( n \frac{\omega}{v_2} \pi \Big) \ \  \ \  \ \ \ \ \ (6)$$

My questions now are:

**1) Do these solutions make sense to you all?**

**2) how can I construct a** $[4 \times 4]$ **determinant out of** $(5)$ **and** $(6)$?

**EDIT $1$**:

I missed the cosine term. Now it should be OK.

- After applying the periodic boundary conditions one gets:

$$\Theta (\theta) = A_1 \sin \Big( n \frac{\omega}{v_1} \theta \Big) + B_1 \cos \Big( n \frac{\omega}{v_1} \theta \Big) \ \ \ \ \ (S.SOL.1)$$

$$\Theta (\theta) = A_2 \sin \Big( n \frac{\omega}{v_2} (2\pi - \theta) \Big) + B_2 \cos \Big( n \frac{\omega}{v_2} (2\pi - \theta) \Big) \ \ \ \ \ (S.SOL.2)$$

- After applying interface conditions one gets:

$$A_1 \sin \Big( n \frac{\omega}{v_1} \pi \Big) + B_1 \cos \Big( n \frac{\omega}{v_1} \pi \Big) = A_2 \sin \Big( n \frac{\omega}{v_2} \pi \Big) + B_2 \cos \Big( n \frac{\omega}{v_2} \pi \Big) \ \  \ \  \ \ \ \ \ (5)$$

$$n\frac{A_1}{v_1} \cos \Big( n \frac{\omega}{v_1} \pi \Big) - n\frac{B_1}{v_1} \sin \Big( n \frac{\omega}{v_1} \pi \Big) = -n\frac{A_2}{v_2} \cos \Big( n \frac{\omega}{v_2} \pi \Big) + n\frac{B_2}{v_2} \sin \Big( n \frac{\omega}{v_2} \pi \Big) \ \  \ \  \ \ \ \ \ (6)$$

Now thinking how to construct the determinant...

**EDIT $2$**:

OK so let's finish it: the determinant is:

$$
    \begin{vmatrix}
    \sin \Big( n \frac{\omega}{v_1} \theta \Big) & \cos \Big( n \frac{\omega}{v_1} \theta \Big) & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & \sin \Big( n \frac{\omega}{v_2} (2 \pi - \theta) \Big) & \cos \Big( n \frac{\omega}{v_2} (2 \pi - \theta) \Big) \\
    \sin \Big( n \frac{\omega}{v_1} \pi \Big) & \cos \Big( n \frac{\omega}{v_1} \pi \Big) & -\sin \Big( n \frac{\omega}{v_2} \pi \Big) & -\cos \Big( n \frac{\omega}{v_2} \pi \Big) \\
    \frac{n}{v_1} \cos \Big( n \frac{\omega}{v_1} \pi \Big) & -\frac{n}{v_1} \sin \Big( n \frac{\omega}{v_1} \pi \Big) & \frac{n}{v_2} \cos \Big( n \frac{\omega}{v_2} \pi \Big) & -n\frac{B_2}{v_2} \sin \Big( n \frac{\omega}{v_2} \pi \Big) \\
    \end{vmatrix}
$$

Note we are given the values of $R$ and $L$ and thus we can compute the determinant (L and R are related by $L = R \theta$).

**EDIT $3$:**

OK the title asks for finding the general solution for the wave equation for waves in a closed loop.

Above I just gave the spatial solutions.

Thus, let me know provide you with the complete general solutions I get (which, of course, have the form $u(\theta, t) = \Theta(\theta)T(t) \ $)

$$(G.S.1)$$

$$u(\theta, t) = A_0 + B_0t + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \Big( A_n \cos(n\omega t) + B_n \sin(n\omega t)\Big) \Big( C_n \cos(n\frac{\omega}{v_1} \theta) + D_n \sin(n\frac{\omega}{v_1} \theta) \Big)$$

$$(G.S.2)$$

$$u(\theta, t) = E_0 + F_0t + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \Big( E_n \cos(\omega t) + F_n \sin(\omega t)\Big) \Big( G_n \cos(\frac{\omega}{v_2} (2 \pi - \theta)) + D_n \sin(\frac{\omega}{v_2} (2 \pi - \theta))$$

Comment: You should end with four amplitudes, each of the boundary conditions give you four equations, giving you $4 \times 4$ matrix.

Comment: @Kevin Thanks, I had missed the $\cos$ term! (EDIT 1). Now I should be able to construct the $4 \times 4$ matrix. Still thinking about it...

Comment: Exactly, that's it. Well done.

Comment: @Kevin OK so the determinant I get is shown above. There are infinitely many eigenvalues, but we can set $n=1$ (for instance) and get the eigenfrequencies associated with such a value. That's a beast though...

Comment: Nice problem. Where does it come from? Has this been given to you?

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Thanks for your comment :) Actually it's a problem from a set that deals with the behavior of waves in, out (corona) and through the sun (both mediums). There're two more exercises I want to comment with you:1) Apply initial conditions to the general solution for the wave going straight out from the sun (this is a problem on reflection of waves; for more details check section 3.2 of the beautiful book 'Introduction to PDE' by Strauss) and 2) Apply initial conditions to the general solution for the wave in a circular loop (general solution that we've found here). So stay tuned :)

Comment: Having restricted to the case of time-periodic solutions, the problem is equivalent to the following QM problem: Find the stationary states for a particle on a ring, where the potential on half the ring is $V_0$ and zero on the rest. (This isn’t so strange: the Schrodinger equation is a wave equation, after all.)